# Selecting DATE from database without time

Tags: c#, mysql

Im trying to select DATE from one of my database tables, I use date as primary key, but when I retrieve DATE there is also time which is 0:00:00. I only need DATE to insert it in combobox and then again write it in databse in another table as PK.

```
public void race_combo()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM race", con);
    MySqlDataReader msdr;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (msdr.Read())
        {
            string team_id = msdr.GetString("id_race");
            MessageBox.Show(team_id);
            comboBox4.Items.Add(team_id);
            comboBox6.Items.Add(team_id);
            comboBox9.Items.Add(team_id);

        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Database table:
http://prntscr.com/g7cadr

This is what I get as output, I belive it has something to do with GetString but im not sure how do it diffrently.

http://prntscr.com/g7cayj

Comment: 1) There is no native type in c# that only has `Date`, there is only `DateTime`. 2) Why are you reading your `date` using `GetString`, are you storing the Date as a string in the DB? If it is a Date then you should read it back as a date (ie. DateTime).

Comment: This is a display layer problem.  Either configure the combobox to show only the date portion or add string values, passing the right format to `ToString`.

Comment: Im not sure how else I should store it, DateTime? Im storing it as DATE only

Comment: @renekton - Correct. Store your types in their native format. int = int, date = date, etc. Do not convert everything to string in your DB.

Comment: Thank you very much, Im kinda new to C# and not familiar with everything so I try whatever I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `DATE_FORMAT` function in your query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(id_race , "%Y-%m-%d") AS id_race FROM race
```

code :

```
public void race_combo()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(id_race , "%Y-%m-%d") AS id_race FROM race", con);
    MySqlDataReader msdr;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (msdr.Read())
        {
            string team_id = msdr.GetString("id_race");
            MessageBox.Show(team_id);
            comboBox4.Items.Add(team_id);
            comboBox6.Items.Add(team_id);
            comboBox9.Items.Add(team_id);

        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First read the value as a `DateTime` by using `GetDateDime()`, then convert to a string in whatever format you choose by using `ToString`:

```
DateTime team_id = msdr.GetDateTime("id_race");
String team_id_string = team_id.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
MessageBox.Show(team_id_string);
comboBox4.Items.Add(team_id_string);
comboBox6.Items.Add(team_id_string);
comboBox9.Items.Add(team_id_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert it in the mySQL query using DATE():

```
SELECT columnname, DATE(datecolumn) FROM .....
```